# No internet connection in chroot environment (customizing iso)

Tags: chroot, ping, iso

I want to customize a Ubuntu Desktop Iso and I have come that far, that I am in the chroot environment.

The problem is that I do not have Internet access in there to install anything.

I just can ping 8.8.8.8, but not www.google.com (for example). Everything goes through a proxy tho, so I made a file apt.conf in the apt folder of the chroot environment but still nothing happens.

I can not run lines like: sudo apt-get update -> It just says "W: Failed to Fetch over and over again"

Does somebody know a solution?
I followed [these steps](http://www.gtkdb.de/index_34_1259.html) (to the part with the sed commands)

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You have internet connection, as evidenced by the ping to `8.8.8.8`. You just don't have DNS name resolution.

See the file `/etc/resolv.conf` in your root file system and copy it to the chroot environment.

Comment: Thank you for your help, I already tried this
sudo cp -a /etc/resolv.conf ~/remastering/newfilesystem/etc/

Comment: I also tried using a simple network without any proxys instead. Still no connection to apt commands

Comment: In the chroot, try `nslookup`, `host`, `dig` or any program of your choice to verify that DNS resolution works.

Comment: Thanks, I did the asked commands but it says on both (nslookup host and dig):
;; connection timed out; no servers could be reached
than I tried ping 8.8.8.8 for fun again and this worked with 10,2ms responsetime 
So weird!#

Comment: There seems to be a firewall between you and the internet. Try with the nameservers from `/etc/resolv.conf` andwith `8.8.8.8`, both from the root and from the chroot.

Comment: The previous given command sudo cp -a /etc/resolv.conf ~/remastering/newfilesystem/etc/ did not do its job I guess. Cause when go in chroot into the /etc fodler the file isnt there. Just a folder named resolvconf (but there is something else in it).
Than I tried creating a new file (tried with sudo vi and nano) with the same fillings than than the root does but it wont let me save it in the chroot

Comment: I copied the root resolv.conf in my home folder and copied it than into the chroot environment. NOW pinging www.google.com AND apt commands work! THANK U!